# Is it true that $x \nmid (q-1) \implies 2^x \not \equiv 1 \mod q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $q$ is a prime number, then from little fermat theorem it is known that

$$2^{q-1} \equiv 1 \mod q$$

My doubt is that

If $x \nmid (q-1)$ then $2^x \not \equiv 1 \mod q$

is true statement or not?

Answer (score 1):

Contrapositive is ($q$ odd prime):

> If $2^x\equiv 1\pmod{\! q}$, then $x\mid q-1$.

It is false: infinitely many counterexamples are given by $x=(q-1)k$ with $k\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 2}$.

$$2^{(q-1)k}\equiv \left(2^{q-1}\right)^k\equiv 1^k\equiv 1\pmod{\! q}$$

but we do not have $(q-1)k\mid q-1$. By the [law of contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) your statement is false.

---

Another question could be: is it true that ($q$ odd prime):

> $2^x\equiv 1\pmod{\! q}\,\Rightarrow\, q-1\mid x$

It is true for a fixed prime $q$ iff $q-1=\text{ord}_q(2)$ (i.e. $q-1$ is the *least* $k$ such that $2^k\equiv 1\pmod{\! q}$; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Multiplicative_order)), but this is often not the case. E.g., $2^3\equiv 1\pmod{\! 7}$ gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it, but I suppose $q$ is an odd prime.

If $x$ it the order of $2$, this results from *Lagrange's theorem*: the multiplicative group $(\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z)^\times$ has order $q-1$, hence all its elements have order a divisor of $q-1$.

Now, if $x$ is only a multiple of the order of $2$, it may not be true. For instance, in $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$, $2$ has order $3$, a divisor of $6$. But also $2^9=1$, and $9$ is definitely not a divisor of $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:  $x = 4$, $q = 3$.  $4 \nmid 2$ and $2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.